# When viewing my readme data on NPM, there's a � between every character

Tags: node.js, npm, markdown, visual-studio-code

I'm new to npm and node in general, just a hobbyist. I wanted to get my head around creating, publishing and using a module through npm.

I made a tiny math library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/thombsaway-maths

Here's the repo so you can see how README.md renders there: https://github.com/Thomas-Elder/hobby.node.maths

I imagine it's some encoding issue, I guess? I'm on Windows 10, writing in vscode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I imagine it's some encoding issue, I guess?

That seems very likely - I downloaded the `README.md` from your repository, and it uses the `UTF-16 LE` encoding, which is less common than the almost universally used `UTF-8`. VSCode displays this information in the status bar:

[image]

You can click this button to change the encoding. Select `Save with Encoding` in the popup menu and then `UTF-8`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've no idea why it was saved in that encoding, but amending it to UTF-8 solved the issue.